# AngularJS - Currency filter with a custom filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple thing I want to do. I want to add a currency filter to the custom filter I wrote.

Here is it:

```js
var app = angular.module('testapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {

  this.people = [{
    name: 'James',
    bank: 5285
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    bank: 849
  }];

});

app.filter('richmeter', function() {
  return function(bank) {
    if (bank > 2500) {
      return bank + ' [RICH]'
    } else {
      return bank;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="people in vm.people | filter:richmeter">
      {{people.name}} has {{people.bank | currency }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this not working? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AngularJS `currency` filter expects the [required amount parameter to be a number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency). Within your `richmeter` filter you appear to be conditionally returning a string, which means that `people.bank` will not function as expected within the `currency` filter.